# When Cross Compiling (Linux to Windows) The Vulkan Loader There Are Many Undefined References to Vulkan Objects

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cross-compiling, vulkan

When using the mingw-32 cmake the code from https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader fails to compile this is the cmake command I am using:`x86_64-w64-mingw32-cmake -DVULKAN_HEADERS_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/ -DVulkanRegistry_DIR=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/vulkan/registry/ -DUSE_MASM=OFF ..`

Which Outputs:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found VulkanHeaders: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include  
-- Found VulkanRegistry: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/vulkan/registry  
-- Detected Vulkan Version 1.2.182
-- Looking for secure_getenv
-- Looking for secure_getenv - not found
-- Looking for __secure_getenv
-- Looking for __secure_getenv - not found
CMake Warning at loader/CMakeLists.txt:27 (message):
  Using non-secure environmental lookups.  This loader will not properly
  disable environent variables when run with elevated permissions.


-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.7.3") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/flippers2652/Documents/Temp/Vulkan-Loader/build
```

Output from make: https://pastebin.pl/view/7467739f

Thank you.

P.S. Distrobution is manjaro.

Comment: I see a warning but no failure. Go ahead and try building with `cmake --build /home/flippers2652/Documents/Temp/Vulkan-Loader/build`. However, it does look like you forgot to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` (maybe you wanted `Release`?) in your configure command.

Comment: @AlexReinking: In the referenced output there are 750 "undefined reference" and following error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a MASM assembler. Which caused it to attempt an assembly thing that it failed to do.